# Spark Python - how to use reduce by key to get minmum/maximum values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, reduce

I have a sample data of maximum and minimum temperatures of some cities in csv format.

```
Mumbai,19,30
Delhi,5,41
Kolkata,20,40
Mumbai,18,35
Delhi,4,42
Delhi,10,44
Kolkata,19,39
```

*I want to find out all time lowest temperature recorded for each city using a spark script in Python.*

Here is my script

```
cityTemp = sc.textFile("weather.txt").map(lambda x: x.split(','))

# convert it to pair RDD for performing reduce by Key

cityTemp = cityTemp.map(lambda x: (x[0], tuple(x[1:])))

cityTempMin = cityTemp.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: min(x[0],y[0]))

cityTempMin.collect()
```

My expected output is as follows

```
Delhi, 4
Mumbai, 18
Kolkata, 19
```

However the script is producing the following output.

```
[(u'Kolkata', u'19'), (u'Mumbai', u'18'), (u'Delhi', u'1')]
```

How do I get the desired output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below solution, if you have to use reduceByKey function :

SCALA:

```
  val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Mumbai", 19, 30),
    ("Delhi", 5, 41),
    ("Kolkata", 20, 40),
    ("Mumbai", 18, 35),
    ("Delhi", 4, 42),
    ("Delhi", 10, 44),
    ("Kolkata", 19, 39))).map(x => (x._1,x._2)).keyBy(_._1)


    df.reduceByKey((accum, n) => if (accum._2 > n._2) n else  accum).map(_._2).collect().foreach(println)
```

PYTHON:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([("Mumbai", 19, 30),
    ("Delhi", 5, 41),
    ("Kolkata", 20, 40),
    ("Mumbai", 18, 35),
    ("Delhi", 4, 42),
    ("Delhi", 10, 44),
    ("Kolkata", 19, 39)])

def reduceFunc(accum, n):
    print(accum, n)
    if accum[1] > n[1]:
        return(n)
    else: return(accum)

def mapFunc(lines):
    return (lines[0], lines[1])

rdd.map(mapFunc).keyBy(lambda x: x[0]).reduceByKey(reduceFunc).map(lambda x : x[1]).collect()
```

Output:

```
(Kolkata,19)
(Delhi,4)
(Mumbai,18)
```

If you don't want to do a reduceByKey. Just a group by followed by min function would give you desired result.

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Mumbai", 19, 30),
        ("Delhi", 5, 41),
        ("Kolkata", 20, 40),
        ("Mumbai", 18, 35),
        ("Delhi", 4, 42),
        ("Delhi", 10, 44),
        ("Kolkata", 19, 39))).toDF("city", "minTemp", "maxTemp")

        df.groupBy("city").agg(min("minTemp")).show
```

Output :

```
+-------+------------+
|   city|min(minTemp)|
+-------+------------+
| Mumbai|          18|
|Kolkata|          19|
|  Delhi|           4|
+-------+------------+
```

Comment: But there are suggestions not to use groupBy because of performance reasons. So I avoided using it. Is there any other way?

Comment: Added a reducebyKey solution to the ans as well.

Comment: @RaviChandra I think the `groupBy` you are referring to is the `groupByKey` method which lowers performance in case of large datasets due to the intermediate shuffling. The `groupBy` used here is a function present in Spark SQL.

Comment: @Sanchit Grover - can you post above RDD solution in pyspark as well?

Comment: @Sanchit Grover.. would be nice to see :-)