# pyspark - how to reducebykey to get the min of the one element of a tuple only

Tags: pyspark

Suppose we have the following data in a csv file (station code, date, data_type, temperature):

'ITE00100554', '18000101', 'TMIN', -7.5

'ITE00100554', '18000101', 'TMIN', -14.8

'ITE00100554', '18000102', 'TMIN', -7.5

'ITE00100554', '18000102', 'TMIN', -14.9

And I try to find the min temperature with corresponding date. The answer should be: 'ITE00100554', '18000102', 'TMIN', -14.9

Here is my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("MinTempDate")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

# parsing (mapping) the input data
def parseLine(line):
    fields = line.split(',')
    stationID = fields[0]
    date = fields[1]
    entryType = fields[2]
    temperature = float(fields[3])
    # creates key/value pairs
    return (stationID, date, entryType, temperature) 


lines = sc.textFile("1800.csv")
parsedLines = lines.map(parseLine)


minTemps = parsedLines.filter(lambda x: "TMIN" in x[2])


stationTemps = minTemps.map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1], x[3])))


minTemps = stationTemps.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (if x[1] >= y[1] y[0] else x[0],min(x[1], y[1])))
```

My problem is the reduceByKey in the last line as the syntax is incorrect and I do not know how to ensure that I got the min temperature and corresponding date.

If I do:

```
minTemps = stationTemps.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: min(x, y))
```

It doesn't work as it will return the minimum of the tuple, which means:
'ITE00100554', '18000101', 'TMIN', -14.8

and it is not what I am looking for.

This post is really close to what I am looking for, however I do not know how to change my syntax to make it work:
[Spark Python - how to use reduce by key to get minmum/maximum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176782/spark-python-how-to-use-reduce-by-key-to-get-minmum-maximum-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the syntax for if clause in lambda as,

```
 minTemps = stationTemps.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (y[0] if x[1] >= y[1] else x[0],min(x[1],y[1])))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("MinTemperatures")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

def parseLine(line):
    fields = line.split(',')
    stationID = fields[0]
    entryType = fields[2]
    temperature = float(fields[3])
    return (stationID, entryType, temperature)

lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://..../1800.csv")
parsedLines = lines.map(parseLine)

minTemps = parsedLines.filter(lambda x: "TMIN" in x[1])
stationTemps = minTemps.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))

miniTemps = stationTemps.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: min(x,y))
results = miniTemps.collect()

for result in results:
    print("Station Id: {0} \n Min Temp: {1}".format(result[0], result[1]))




Output:

Station Id: ITE00100554 
 Min Temp: -148.0
Station Id: EZE00100082 
 Min Temp: -135.0
```

Comment: Please describe your changes, why and how this resolves the issue. The differences are not that eye-catching.